# Security Warning prompt when using a service to launch an unsigned program from local HDD

Tags: windows-xp, security, windows-services, application-launch

I have a remote Windows Embedded box (basically a limited-feature copy of WinXPSP3), on which I have a Windows service whose only purpose in life is to make sure that a copy of a particular application is running. If not, it uses a .NET Process.Start() call in code to launch a copy.

We have this service and program running on nearly 1300 boxes much like this one without issue. However, with this particular box, when the service (running as "local system") tries to launch the software, a Security Warning prompt pops up and the software doesn't launch. The service then repeats the command (because the software didn't start) and the end result is a block of 100 security warning dialogs and no running software. Obviously this is a problem, as we cannot babysit this box (or any other really) and the software is critical to our business operations, which involve health and life safety.

When launching the software as the default logged-in user, the software starts up fine. The software resides on the hard drive of the box in question and not in any network share, so the zone should be "My Computer". The file was "blocked" but has since been "unblocked", with no change.

Assume no changes to the service or software are possible, but that I can do anything to the Windows environment itself such as changing the user account running the service, modifying Internet Options, Group Policy, etc. Also assume that .exe files are listed as "safe" low-risk files in GP, that the Intranet security settings will not prompt when launching an application, and that there are no Trusted sites/domains. Basically I've tried everything that a Google search says to do to disable Security Warnings for all applications and the problem persists.

Comment: Can you post the text of the security warning?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim infoStart As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
Dim strFile As String = "SomeFileName.exe"
infoStart.FileName = strFile
infoStart.UseShellExecute = False '<---- this is what you want
Process.Start(infoStart)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the certificate the app was signed with to the **computer's** "trusted publisher" list. You will either need to do this this through GP or through manually opening it through mmc. You may have added the cert to the **User's** cert store, and that is why it is not trusted when you run it as system. See if it works after you add it to the computer store.

[image]